# Jenkins GitHub pull request builder - $ghprbSourceBranch is coming blank

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins GitHub pull request builder for execute shell, all the below are coming blank.

```
echo 'ghprbActualCommit: ' $ghprbActualCommit
echo 'ghprbActualCommitAuthor: ' $ghprbActualCommitAuthor
echo 'ghprbActualCommitAuthorEmail: ' $ghprbActualCommitAuthorEmail
echo 'ghprbPullDescription: ' $ghprbPullDescription
echo 'ghprbPullId: ' $ghprbPullId
echo 'ghprbPullLink: ' $ghprbPullLink
echo 'ghprbPullTitle: ' $ghprbPullTitle
echo 'ghprbSourceBranch: ' $ghprbSourceBranch
echo 'ghprbTargetBranch: ' $ghprbTargetBranch
echo 'sha1: ' $sha1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get these values in the job which is triggered on pull request:) Earlier I was trying to get these values in a job which was getting triggered post merge request.